# SQL Server : combine like usernames

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to combine similar names that are inside the `UserName` row.

If I had the following:

```
Bob Barker
Johnny Rogers
Bob Barker
Bob Barker
Neal String
Bobby McNight
Johnny Rogers
```

I would like it to be:

```
Bob Barker
Johnny Rogers
Neal String
Bobby McNight
```

My query so far is this:

```
SELECT [UserName]
    ,[AffNumber]
    ,[blah]
    ,[tDate]
    ,[DIF]     
FROM [WWebsite].[dbo].[Log], [WWebsite].[dbo].[Users]            
WHERE blah = '62055'
AND tDate > '2013-12-31 00:00:00' 
AND tDate < '2014-04-01 00:00:00'
```

And although I do get results I keep getting dupes of the `UserName`.

**UPDATE**

The `Log` table has the following columns:

```
id, UserId, DIF, WalkDate,...
```

The `Users` table has the following columns:

```
id, UserName, Weight,...
```

Comment: Are the other columns returning same values too?

Comment: IS it just usernames or are all those other fields the same too, such as their AffNumber, Blah, tDate, Dif, etc?  If they are different, what do you expect to happen with those other fields?  Do you want a COUNT of them, AVG, SUM, etc?  They are distinct records, so what's the plan to "group" them?

Comment: @shree.pat18 The UserName

Comment: Why don't you do just `SELECT DISTINCT UserName FROM ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [UserName]
    ,[AffNumber]
    ,[blah]
    ,[tDate]
    ,[DIF]     
FROM [WWebsite].[dbo].[Log] a 
JOIN [WWebsite].[dbo].[Users] b on a.UserId = b.Id            
WHERE blah = '62055'
AND tDate > '2013-12-31 00:00:00' 
AND tDate < '2014-04-01 00:00:00'
```

if with those you would get the duplicates as well u may try doing this:

```
SELECT [UserName]
    ,max([AffNumber])
    ,max([blah])
    ,max([tDate])
    ,max([DIF])
FROM [WWebsite].[dbo].[Log]
JOIN [WWebsite].[dbo].[Users] b on a.UserId = b.Id      
WHERE blah = '62055'
AND tDate > '2013-12-31 00:00:00' 
AND tDate < '2014-04-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY UserName
```